# How to ignore params when `parseObject` in fastjson?

Tags: java, fastjson

I use the [fastjson](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.alibaba/fastjson/1.2.12) to deal with the `JSON`. When I was trying to derialize the `JSON` string to a bean, I got an exception. I debuged into the code and find out there was something wrong with a param when deserializeing. So I wanna ignore it. I used the method `parseObject`

```
public static <T> T parseObject(String text, Class<T> class)
```

I tried the `transient` but it didn't work.

Comment: Please share the error message.

Comment: @TimoSta it's a NPE, just because I change the setter of the variable. So I wanna ignore this var

Answer (score 0):

`@JSONField(serialize = false)` can fix it